# What exactly is fringes in interference of light?

Tags: optics, waves

In Young's double slit experiment interference patterns are formed.  And my question is what is meant by "fringe". Is it only dark band or bright band? I am confused because formula for width of fringe is $\frac{\lambda D}{d}$ which is equivalent to Dark band and Bright Band together. So what's happening?

[image]

As you can clearly see by shifting the width of fringe in fig.  It is equivalent to both dark and bright region.  But in my book it's vaguely telling that the dark and bright region are separately fringe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram you posted shows the fringe width being measured from the center of one light band to the center of the next light band; or from the center of one dark band to the center of the next dark band.

Thus the total fringe width is equal to the 1/2 the width of one light band, plus the width of a dark band, plus a second 1/2 the width of one light band. Which is equivalent to the width of one light band plus one dark band.

I don't see any inconsistency.

Comment: So I can say that one fringe is one light and one black band(or equivalent) ? Or be precise to definition you gave?

Comment: @user9339131, yes, a fringe is one complete cycle from whatever point you choose (brightest point, darkest point, halfway between as the fringe gets brighter, whatever) back to the next similar point.